# Flexbox: Two even columns - big image (with aspect-ratio) and content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to create an information section that includes an image and content next to it.

It should look like this:
[image]

I have already written a little bit of code, but it does not seem to be the best solution: everything works fine, but code is not graceful.

Please, have a look:

```css
/* Simple reset */
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

.information {
  display: flex;
  gap: clamp(5rem, 10vw, 8rem);
}

.information > * {
  width: 50%; /* Using the 'width' property. */ 
}

.information-content {
  align-self: center;
  color: white;
}

.information-image {
  align-self: flex-start;

  object-fit: cover;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1.10;
  
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="information">
            <img
                class="information-image"
                alt="Products for companies & Startups"
                src="https://s3-alpha-sig.figma.com/img/6630/3672/40959a0086f9fbb8418c0829b277dd93?Expires=1670198400&Signature=gpQ5NqRXp9omRHkjCl718I9WPLqfx4xPKp1CQSMKbEnRCU7izmQIXkcn6zI6Z17p8Q7Li-wBAXb3P2Jg9qEuJauFeKqErbl4jgW950K35-LeX394hN7fJ7UEPmkgGSqB-drY1QdU7NZVV4QKTrZ0QBuw47xVBPOOfJMQO8NPOpZkx43UbbkS1yGgnxN5tELyriz9e8pH6pXO8AnJx7zvGz4mm3InyHOySUcb3ibVPa9XKJ8fyxPnkBeVoYFvwpiVddEs7uVNqCkCRuN2dJIIQg78FB-6TYX13nQ~NxvhG2059ks2q52a9p0N-DSmSYE-Yt-jedbJ1fEt3cZVnIfzUw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAINTVSUGEWH5XD5UA"
            />
            <div class="information-content">
                <h2>
                    My main goal is to keep my customers satisfied.
                </h2>
                <p>
                    Even with skills that are primarily mental, such as 
                    computer programming or speaking a foreign language.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Even with skills that are primarily mental, such as 
                    computer programming or speaking a foreign language.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

My concern is the `width` property set on each child of my flex parent. As far as I know, using `width` inside flexbox is not the best idea? However, when I try to use the `flex-basis` property, everything breaks.

**Note**: I cannot use `display: grid` because the image can be after the content - with `grid` I will have to change the order and the code will become more complicated.

Comment: I see a lot of mis-assumptions here. Why is it not a good idea to use `width` for flex child elements? Why can't you use grid? You can change the grid-auto-placement just as you can in flexbox (even `direction: RTL` would work).

Comment: @tacoshy yes, you're right that those were miss-assumptions. I mistakenly thought that `grid` was a bad idea. But, unfortunately, when I try to use it, the image overflows and `aspect-ratio` doesn't seem to work properly (I use Firefox). Do you think it is a good idea to ask about this in another question?

Comment: _Do you think it is a good idea to ask about this in another question?_ Maybe so and try to be a bit more clear what would be the desired outcome :)